# Asking about Jquery-min and Jquery-ui

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery-min CDN file from google hosting in a simple HTML, hosted by Apache 2.4 , and script javascript jquery files. The jquery-min script file works fine, but I can't understand why the jquery-ui script does not function well, for example the jquery-ui calender functions, but the jquery-ui buttons with icons inside do not work. How can I fix this this ? Is there a problem with the script I am using, or am I not writing the code very well ?
The code I am using is below:

Jquery Test

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#button').button({
        label: 'Test',
        icons: {
            primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus',
            secondary: null
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <body>
    <button id="button">Button Tag </button>
    <input type="submit" value="Input Tag(submit)" />

    <p>
        <img id="tease" src="tease.jpeg" />
    </p>

    <div id="stage" style="background-color:cc0;">
        STAGE
    </div>

    <input type="button" id="driver" value="load Data">
    </input>

</body>

Comment: When you use jQuery UI, you also need to load one of the stylesheets.

Comment: Don't put HTML in the comments, put it in the question.

Comment: Above is the HTML part I am using, somehow I could not include it with the Javscript above,the editor did't let this.

Comment: Paste the HTML into the question, mark it with the mouse, and type Control-k to mark it as code.

Comment: Also do not forget to mention `type="text/javascript"` in `script`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao That's not necessary, javascript is the default.

Comment: I am actually using these two scripts which are hosted by google, do you know if these are correct scripts? Is the problem in the codethen ?

Comment: Which google hosted jquery and stylesheets will work together for the jquery-min and jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

You need to load one of the jQuery UI stylesheets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```